# How to remove unwanted length while priting

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```
<div class="print-case-detail-modal">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>



function printdiv(printpage)
{
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
return false;
}
```

Now the problem is when we print this, it take lot of white space in height i mean unneccssary height comes while printing i want it should print only that contain which is available on div no other white space in in length

Comment: Make a print stylesheet.

Comment: What do you mean? i have attached the default printer which print the reciept the exisint software priinting only content but my code printing other white space also in more hight. how to do stylehseet

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) out. With the `@media` rules you can write a print stylesheet.

Comment: Instead of building a new document. Just have a stylesheet that you can apply to the current one that changes the layout to one that prints the way you want.

Comment: @ScottMarcus can you give me some link so that i can see how can i create stylesheet and link with print function.